# Htaccess URL rewrite default & pairs in URL

Tags: regex, .htaccess

I currently have a URL structure which typically reads

```
RewriteRule ^/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/  /index.php?app=$1&action=$2&id=$3 [NC,L,QSA]
```

My issue is, it automatically attempts to include any static files / images etc.

The pattern typically translates to

```
www.example.com
www.example.com/user/
www.example.com/user/edit/123
```

and allows for an additional query string to be appended if need be.

Im kinda stuck on how to exclude other media types, is my pattern not written correctly?

thanks in advance

Comment: You need to show samples of URLs you want to exclude.

Comment: Add `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f` condition before your rule.